# Switching Between Two Slideshows with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I have a web page with a slideshow. The slideshow has three pictures. I would like to  have a button on the page which enables users to switch between this slideshow and another with five different pictures. How would I program this button with JavaScript and where would I add the second slideshow in the HTML?

Current HTML:

```
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="img1.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="img2.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="img3.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
<button>Switch Slideshow</button>
```

Current CSS:

```
 /* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor:pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

Current JavaScript:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to first be able to create your slideshow dynamically. Only then will you be able to swap in-and-out different slides. I tried not to refactor your existing code. Also, I did not use jQuery (which I would use personally). Just generate the markup for each slide and set it on the slides div. I had to create an inner div so that the buttons do not get overridden.

```js
var slideshowIndex = 1;
var slideIndex = 1;
var slideshows = [
  [
    'http://placehold.it/500x300/f00/0ff?text=Foo',
    'http://placehold.it/500x300/0f0/f0f?text=Bar',
    'http://placehold.it/500x300/00f/ff0?text=Baz'
  ], [
    'http://placehold.it/500x300/f70/07f?text=Fizz',
    'http://placehold.it/500x300/0f7/f07?text=Buzz',
    'http://placehold.it/500x300/70f/7f0?text=Bang'
  ]
];
var buttonTextArr = [ 'Show Images', 'Show Pages' ];
function createSlides(slides) {
  return slides.map(function(slide, index) {
    return [
      '<div class="mySlides fade">',
      '<div class="numbertext">' + (index + 1) + ' / ' + slides.length + '</div>',
      '<img src="' + slide + '">',
      '<div class="text">Caption #' + (index + 1) + '</div>',
      '</div>'
    ].join('');
  }).join('');
}
function createDots(slides) {
  return slides.map(function(slide, index) {
    return '<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(' + (index + 1) + ')"></span>'
  }).join('');
}
function loadSlideshow(slides) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('slideshow-slides')[0].innerHTML = createSlides(slides);
  document.getElementsByClassName('dots')[0].innerHTML = createDots(slides);
}
function loadNextSlideshow() {
  slideshowIndex = (slideshowIndex + 1) % 2;
  loadSlideshow(slideshows[slideshowIndex]);
  slideIndex = 1; // Reset index
  showSlides(slideIndex);
  document.getElementsByClassName('switch')[0].innerHTML = buttonTextArr[slideshowIndex];
}

loadNextSlideshow(); // Load the slideshow

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}
function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  text-shadow: 0.05em 0.05em 0.25em #000;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from { opacity: 0.4 }
  to   { opacity: 1 }
}
@keyframes fade {
  from { opacity: 0.4 }
  to   { opacity: 1 }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="slideshow-slides"></div>
  <a class="prev" onClick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onClick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br />
<div class="dots" style="text-align:center"></div>
<button class="switch" onClick="loadNextSlideshow()">Switch Slideshow</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great. May I also ask if you'd know how to tweak the JavaScript to make the text on the button change when you click it. So, let's say the text on the button starts off as "Show Images", after you click on it, I'd like it to display "Show Pages", and then back to "Show Images" if you click again.

Comment: @A.Kimberley: I added a text array which is based off of the slideshow index. See the updated notes by [viewing the history](/posts/40345397/revisions).

Comment: @Polywhirl: Thanks! That also works very well. Right, I'm off to learn JavaScript and Jquery properly so I can attempt some of this stuff myself!

Answer (score 0):

Created plunker here. Please refer below link.

https://plnkr.co/edit/xso6MfwOxQJ4PlDpW90y?p=preview

```
HTML
<div class="slideshow-container">
 <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
 <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
 <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
 <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
 <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
<button>Switch Slideshow</button>

JavaScript: 


var slideShowIndex = 1;
var slideShows= [
   [
        {

          'image': 'img1.jpg',
          'caption': 'Caption Text'
        },
        {
          'image': 'img1.jpg',
          'caption': 'Caption Text'
        },
        {
          'image': 'img1.jpg',
          'caption': 'Caption Text'
        }
    ],
    [
        {

          'image': 'img1.jpg',
          'caption': 'Caption Text'
        },
        {
          'image': 'img1.jpg',
          'caption': 'Caption Text'
        },
        {
          'image': 'img1.jpg',
          'caption': 'Caption Text'
        },
         {
          'image': 'img1.jpg',
          'caption': 'Caption Text'
        },
         {
          'image': 'img1.jpg',
          'caption': 'Caption Text'
        }
    ]
  ]

buildSlideShow();

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}


function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}


function buildSlideShow(){
  var slideText = '';
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow-container");
  var slidesToRender = slideShows[slideShowIndex-1];
  slidesToRender.forEach(function(value,index){
    slideText += '<div class="mySlides fade"><div class="numbertext">'+ index+1+ '/'+slidesToRender.length + '</div><img src="'+value.image+'" style="width:100%"><div class="text">'+value.caption+'</div></div>';
  });
  slides[0].innerHtml = slideText;

}
```

hope this works for you.