# TypeError: slides[(slideIndex - 1)] is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typeerror

I have a question regarding a slide show I am building for an assignment. My debugging skills are not the best as I am new to HTML and JS. My problem comes from getting a typeError from a line in my slideshow JS. The problem is in this block here:

```
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 4000);
}
```

My HTML is:

```
    <img class="mySlides" src="http://www.kitchenaid.com/images/global/masthead-major-appliances.jpg">
<img class="mySlides" src="http://www.depotkitchen.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/kitchen-aid-appliances-1.jpg">
<img class="mySlides" src="http://washburns.com/media/k2/galleries/11/stainlesssteelkitchen2.jpg">
<img class="mySlides" src="https://www.appliancedepot.com/media/R37672.jpg">
```

The issue is with the line `slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";` I am getting the error:

> TypeError: slides[{slideIndex-1)] is undefined.

Does anyone know a solution to this? Thanks for any help!

Here is a screenshot of the error on the debugging page:

[Debugging page and error show cased](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4838l.png)

Comment: If there are no elements with that class `slides[0]` will not have a `style` property. Are you sure there are actually elements with that class?

Comment: Can you confirm the slides array has at least one item?

Comment: So would I need to remove the -1 in the line?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/mmry6wes/. Seeing a sample of your HTML would help a lot here.

Comment: Also, yes, there are 3 elements in the array.

Comment: I have edited the original post to show the HTML the images in the slideshow are coming from.

Comment: Still works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/mmry6wes/1/

Comment: I assume you are trying to modify the following script from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40343951/switching-between-two-slideshows-with-javascript/ ;)

Comment: Do you know why I might getting this error on this?  I realize that the slideshow does work, but the error is blocking other parts of script that I have written to complete the assignment.

Comment: Unless you can show us code or an example which recreates the error, then there's not much anyone can do to help you

Comment: Yes, my teacher has us reference W3 schools for help on programming as its an online class and this is an example from their site, I am just trying to understand where I am going wrong as I go through it.

Comment: Well your code works correctly, but the error you've posted contains a typo `slides[{slideIndex-1)]` though I expect that's a typo you've made in the question rather than the actual problem with the code.

Comment: I have updated the original post to showcase the error I am receiving in the debugger when running the htm page.  Does this help?  Is there other information I can provide to solve this?

Comment: Don't use [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/), use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn) instead.

Comment: I think your issue is that the `mySlides` image elements are not loaded on the page at the time the script is run. Wait for the page to load or put the script at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Mr. Polywhirl and i also love the name!  Also, moving the script to the bottom of the page solved my issues!! thanks so much.  - Quick question, I thought that it was in JS convention to put the script in the heading?

Comment: Placing it at the bottom of the page ensures all of the HTML is loaded before the JS executes, conventions vary a lot about where to place it, if you're using JQuery (as you've tagged the question) you could leave it in the head and wrap your code in a `$(document).ready(function(){ //Code here })` to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Ah this makes more sense, I will be more careful in analyzing where to place the script.  I appreciate everyone's help!

Comment: what is the slides[slideIndex-1] doing ? why cant we use slides[slideIndex] to make the current slide visible. i cant understand the -1 part here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.
load the js file after the slider and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found that the <span> tags with "dot" class is removed, so I added &nbsp; between <span></span> tags and my problem solved.